# calendly url not show in angular mat dialog box

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, modal-dialog, calendly

Calendly url not show in angular mat dialog box:

```
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" 
        style="min-width:320px;height:580px;" 
        data-auto-load="true">
    <div class="my-5 p-3 container bg-white text-dark">
        <div class="calendly-inline-widget" 
            data-url="https://calendly.com/demo" 
            style="min-width:320px;height:700px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

Comment: can you please describe your issue in detail...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.